# Remote Desktop - Check For Oveheating

Tags: cpu, temperature, overheating

Is it possible to check the current temperature of CPU through software (control panel, task manager, third party service) and whether the computer is overheating?
I am connecting to a computer remotely and running CPU intensive code utilizing multiple cores through parallel computing and need to keep a check on the CPU temperatures.

I'm connecting to the machine through a Windows 7 remote desktop session and the remote machine is also running on Windows 7.

Comment: What os is the desktop running? What sort of remote access do you have? We don't have sufficient data to help you.

Comment: @Aziz: Have you tried HWMonitor (http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)?

Comment: @James I haven't. But it looks useful on a first glance. I'm going to explore it now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPUID will monitor temperature and does not require installation.

http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html